# removing provisioning profile from xcode

Tags: iphone

How can I remove a previously installed development provisioning profile from xcode?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like you'd want to remove it from your iPhone. I'm not in front of my Mac at the moment but I believe that within XCode there is an Organizer (Look under the view menu option, make sure your iPhone is plugged in) you can open up  where you can access your provisioning profile to remove or replace it. I'll check when I get home and update this answer.

Also, if you need to remove just the provisioning file for a single project you can do so by navigating to the build folder of your project and deleting it from there.

If you need to remove your signing keys you can do that through your keychain admin tool.

Edit: Within XCode goto Window->Organizer This will open up the organizer. From there you can do what you need to do to remove the provisioning file.

Answer (score 149):

They're stored in: `~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles`

You'll want to restart XCode to refresh the list.

Comment: @mxcl: Not really, you can still use 'iPhone Configuration Utility' to manage your Provisioning Profiles.

Comment: Yes you can use iPhone Config Utility to manage all your provisioning profiles (since you cannot do it in Xcode 5 anymore) but deleting 400+ provisioning profiles one by one in iPhone Configuration Utility is no fun at all. Thxs @Ramin for pointing out where to find them all so I can delete in bulk!

Comment: help me a lot: each time when i delete profiles from organiser, then return after sync with iTunes. but when i delete all from this folder - tadam - now all works like magic

Comment: This one should be accepted answer, according to the question.

Comment: They just come back when you sync again.

Comment: Removing the App IDs related to the provisioning profile(s) fixed my issue.

Answer (score 25):

Xcode keeps provisioning profiles at following directory:

```
~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning\ Profiles
```

To remove old profile from Xcode just delete it's file and restart Xcode. Profile file names are somewhat cryptic, so use the following command to show their real names:

```
grep -a -A1 "<key>Name</key>" *.mobileprovision | grep -v "<key>Name</key>" | grep -v "^--"
```

If you need more than a name, for example list of UDIDs, this command shows all content of particular provisioning profile:

```
security cms -D -i xxx.mobileprovision
```

Update: recently Apple added ability to preview `*.mobileprovision` files with standard Finder app.

Comment: This must be the most professional answer. You saved my life.

Comment: This grep command is so cool, why stackoverflow doesn't provide an ability to add answers to favorites?

Answer (score 9):

I've had trouble deleting provisioning profiles in Xcode 5.

An alternative way is to use the [iPhone Configuration Utility](http://support.apple.com/downloads/#iphone%20configuration%20utility), which displays provisioning profiles installed on your system and allows you to remove them (select and press delete key).

Comment: This is definitely the easiest way since Xcode doesn't give you the option any more

Answer (score 8):

I have yet to find a way to delete provisioning profiles individually (Xcode 5).

The only way I can get them to go away is by **removing the App IDs** related to the provisioning profile(s).
(In Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles in the Member Center)

Obviously this might not be optimal for you - but if you have been using a test app id it is the way to go.

---

Ways I have unsuccessfully tried to remove provisioning profiles:

(they reappear after a refresh in xcode/preferences/accounts/details)

1. Apples Developer website
2. Using iPhone Configuration Utility
3. Directly in the folder they reside (~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning
   Profiles)

Comment: "The only way I can get them to go away is by removing the App IDs"
Thank you! Been searching high and low and this worked.

Answer (score 7):

I think you have to open keychain.app then go to Certificates and delete them there.

Comment: That's the correct answer. I couldn't delete the certificates from the xcode.

Comment: What exactly do you delete? I see a bunch of different profiles that could be related to Xcode.

Answer (score 6):

With XCode 5, the profiles are now in Xcode -> Preferences -> Accounts. To delete a duplicate of a newly downloaded provisioning profile, you just need to select your account on this page, and click the refresh button at the bottom left under the provisioning profile list.

Comment: It's useless for profiles of which you don't have account.

Answer (score 5):

From Xcode 5 and above

We can't find the certificate installed in xcode from organizer tab.

Go to

step 1

In xcode build settings, select your provisioning profile want to delete

step 2

Select the Provisioning profile in build settings under "under Provisioning Profile", and click other. It will show a 33 hexa digit number. copy that.

step 3

go to
~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles

and search for that copied number as a name in provisioning profile.

Delete it. :)

Comment: Most simple answer. By the way, in step 2, it should be "under Provisioning Profile", not "code signing identity", which is misleading.

Answer (score 0):

go to iphone configuration utility->select provision profile->click backspace (worked for xcode 6)