# Xcode build warning - Target Integrity - Provisioning profile is expiring only for the ProjectnameTests Target

Tags: xcode, build, warnings

All my apps that i've created so far do this. It does nothing to the app or being able to run it but it's just annoying always having that 1 warning.

I'm Using 
Xcode 4.2 
OSX 10.7.3

This is the actual warning:

-Target Integrity
Provisioning profile is expiring

Here's an image of it just so I don't have to try and explain. (Edited it and put 'Project' where my actual project name was for privacy)

[image]

Thanks for any help!

Comment: check this link:http://stackoverflow.com/a/922830/845115

Comment: I am having this same problem, but only with old projects. New projects do not give this warning. My provisioning profile has recently been renewed, so is NOT about to expire. Is there somewhere buried in the project or target settings that needs to be changed? These projects were 3.x, so that may be a clue. Thanks for any help

Answer (score 120, accepted):

I had the same issue.

Worked out in the end it was Xcode warning about some expired profiles generally - not ones specifically linked to the current project.

To fix I went to Organizer/ Devices Tab and under Library select Provisioning Profiles

I had two profiles in the list that had expired - I didn't need them so I just right clicked and deleted them.

Warning then went away.

Comment: It is weird. I had several profiles already expired, but none about to expire (all valid ones expire in 2013). Deleted the expired ones and now the warning is gone.

Comment: See the updated answer from TheEye, this has changed in Xcode 5+, now it's not managed through Organizer any more.

Comment: It is not working anymore for Xcode 6, you can see [a new answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9287087/xcode-build-warning-target-integrity-provisioning-profile-is-expiring-only-f/30272020#30272020)

Answer (score 37):

This is a bit different with Xcode 5 now when working with Teams ...

I go the same warning of an expiring old profile which didn't exist anymore - but it still did exist in the local Account setting for the connected team in Xcode (`Xcode -> Preferences -> Accounts -> <team account in question> -> View Details`). So I just did a refresh on these profiles, and **yes, the warning was gone**.

Unfortunately there are many more expired profiles for other apps in this team account which I just synched into my local Account setting (and I can't just remove them, as it's a client's account ..) - and now **Xcode complains about all of them being expired**. Guess you should be happy with what you got sometimes, it can get worse ...

Comment: I had to go into my Apple Developer Portal > Provisioning Profiles > Edit > [deleted all invalid and expired] > then went and refreshed my Team Details like above. This removed the errors.

Comment: This worked for me using Xcode 6.2 after regenerating an *invalid* profile that was also expiring.

Answer (score 18):

I got the same warning on my old project today.

I tried this, and the warning went away.

At 'Build Settings' -> 'Code Signing Identity', Choose 'Automatic Profile selector'.

Answer (score 11):

For **Xcode 6** you need to:

1. go to the Preferences (**Cmd + ,**)
2. **Accounts**
3. choose your account
4. choose your team
5. Click view details
6. Choose provisioning profile from warning
7. right click (show in Finder)
8. remove from Finder

Now the warning should disappear or you will need to repeat above steps for another warning

Comment: Thanks! Similar to @TheEye's answer, but clearer (for me): +1

Comment: At Step 6, how to choose the warning-causing profile? The profile's name has nothing similar to the file name. So I deleted all of them, then download profiles of my account, and import profiles of which I don't have account. And I solved it.

Answer (score 7):

I deleted all the provisioning profile from

`cd ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning\ Profiles/`

and it's gone.

You can use this [shell script](https://github.com/InderKumarRathore/ListProvisioningProfileName) the get the names of the provisioning profiles

Answer (score 4):

It is a warning that your provisioning profile is about to expire and you should renew it.
You can do this at Apple's developer center website. If your developer profile program is also about to expire, you should renew it too.

Answer (score 2):

I had to also restart Xcode after deleting the old profiles to get the warnings to go away.

Answer (score 2):

I have the similar problem, Xcode say one provisioning profile is expiring.
Then I go to the developer.apple.com to delete the expiring provisioning profile, it fixed.
Hope can help you.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem because a provisioning profile I used was signed with a certificate that was revoked/expired. First, go to the member center and delete expired and invalid provisioning profiles. Regenerate the ones you need. To clean up Xcode, go to Preferences-> Accounts, select your account.

Click view details.

Right click any profile -> Show in finder. Delete all of them. Then go back to XCode, close details and reopen (to refresh) and re-download the ones you need (there'll be a download button for each profile).

Warning gone. Xcode might complain about code signing issues, but clicking "Resolve" automatically clears this up.

Then everything worked.