# More details for Provision Profile list in Xcode 5

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I've updated to Xcode 5 and tried to export an adhoc build today for one of my clients to upload to TestFlight.

I've done this countless times without any issues. However, it turns out that the export screen in Xcode 5 only shows half of the information, so I don't know what the bundle ID is for the app (like Xcode 4).

Xcode 5: **iOS Team Provision Profile: ***

Xcode 4: **iOS Team Provision Profile: com.bundleID**

With the attached screen it took trial and error (multiple exports and uploads) to eventually find the correct provision for the app.

Is there anyway to bring back the bundle ID to this screen, or to rename the provision?

Thank you for you

[image]

Comment: Can you check the provisioning profiles in your developer's a/c? I think you need to clean up the account. XCode 5 is messing up by creating multiple team profiles with wildcard bundle id. You can also check the profiles in XCode->Preferences->Accounts->Apple ID->Team Name->View Details

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I've been in that section, but I couldn't find anything to fix the situation

Comment: Did you try login to your Apple developer's a/c and check the team profiles list there?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and have filed a bug report.

found this [removing provisioning profile from xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/922695/removing-provisioning-profile-from-xcode)

So I opened ...
~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning\ Profiles

Then went down each one to see the modification date and then double checked by using a quickview on the mobile provision.

Then removed the out of date one.

quickview from https://coderwall.com/p/kwb8ig

Comment: Glad I'm not the only one with this problem. Thanks for your suggestion, that looks like a good option until the bug is fixed.

Comment: My bug report has been flagged as a duplicate but the email contained the statement "THE INFORMATION CONTAINED IN THIS MESSAGE IS UNDER NON-DISCLOSURE" siggghhhhhh