# How remove a old provisioning profile in xcode 5?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode5, provisioning-profile

I've install different provisioning profile in my xcode 5, before for remove it you had a session with all provisioning profile installed on the mac, but now this session disappear, how can I have access to this session now?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

The best way to do this in XCode 5 is using an [iPhone Configuration Utility](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1465?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US). It lets you manually delete duplicates of provisioning profiles with ease and speed.

[image]

I keep Xcode closed when I do this just in case.

Edit:
For anyone wondering how to actually 'delete'. There are only two ways: a.  menu ->  b. Hit the  /  keyboard button.

Comment: THANK YOU. This was bugging me for weeks.

Comment: Mavericks: Apple says to download `iPhone Configurator` instead of `iPhone Configuration Utility`. But I couldn't figure out any way to delete the provisioning profiles using Configurator. Despite Mavericks, the old Utility installed fine and easily deleted the provisioning profile.

Comment: @funroll You can delete profile by pressing keyboard Delete or Backspace key

Comment: There are two Apples: one creates gorgeous devices with amazing software for the public, the other, controlled by satan himself, creates Xcode, iPhone Configurator and now this Apple Configurator. This other Apple hates developers.

Comment: For anyone wondering how to actually 'delete'.
There are only two ways:
a. <Edit> menu -> <Delete>
b. Hit the <Delete> / <Backspace> keyboard button.

Comment: Holy smokes, they sure don't make this easy do they?  The delete key on a PC keyboard din't work form me - I had to use delete from the edit menu.

Comment: I'm using Yosemite 10.10.2,  iPhone Configuration Utility Version 3.5 (289), and IOS 8.2 on my iPad. The delete menu item is grayed out for the provisioning profiles, and the Delete key just causes the Utility to beep. Thoughts?

Comment: I can't find this app. Anyone have a link?

Comment: Apple Deleted from repository but download from the another resources http://mac.softpedia.com/get/System-Utilities/iPhone-Configuration-Utility.shtml

Answer (score 61):

You can delete the files directly from `~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles`

Open finder, ⌘-Shift-G, and paste in the above path. Restart Xcode afterward.

[Check out this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/922695/removing-provisioning-profile-from-xcode) for other suggestions.

Comment: I don't have any folder named MobileDevice

Comment: @htafoya I didn't see it either, but using the ⌘-Shift-G worked miracles.

Comment: Deleted from here and on the website but the next sync they all came back again.

Comment: I agree with this. Also If we need to add new provisional profile etc, remove them from Keychain Access too.

Comment: Just to say, it's now June 2016, we're upto Xcode 7.3.1, and this hopelessly unfriendly method of removing old Provisioning Profiles is still the only way to get rid of them.  Apple must *really* hate developers...

Answer (score 20):

Mirko's answer is correct- however, below I am trying to explain "why-it-is-so" on XCode5.
On XCode5, you are not supposed to/allowed to directly delete a provisioning profile- I think Apple has changed the paradigm a little bit and wanted to streamline the process, while making the provisioning and signing of binaries more secure. The idea on XCode5, is to allow you to login using your dev apple ID and then X-Code will be in sync with all your provisioning profiles. If you want to delete a profile (probably expired or redundant), you go to your dev profile and delete it- since the X-Code has all the details about your apple ID and provisioning profiles (as seen in the screenshot)- it will sync itself with your latest list of profiles- you do not have to worry about deleting those from X-Code anymore (and hence you can not delete these from X-Code anymore).
[image]

Comment: This is a much more complete answer.

Comment: removing profiles from the developer portal doesn't work since they will reappear when you refresh your account in Xcode

Comment: I wasn't able to get the expired provisioning profile to go away through any of the automatic syncing that Xcode 5 does. Removing it manually worked.

Answer (score 4):

To delete a duplicate of an edited provisioning profile, you can also go to Xcode -> Preferences -> Accounts, select your account, and hit the refresh button on the bottom left corner under the provisioning profile list.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways for deleting your old  provisioning profiles from Xcode.
1. Xcode Preferences
2. iPhone Configuration Utility Software.

1. Xcode Preferences -> Go Xcode -> click on left hand side top toolbar option Xcode -> Click Preferences -> Accounts, select your account, and hit the refresh button on the bottom left corner under the provisioning profile list.

By doing this you can delete your provisioning profiles.

2. iPhone Configuration Utility Software -> Install this software -> Open Software -> Provisioning Profiles -> find list of your all profile -> Press Backspace button, it will ask to delete provisioning profile ->Click on  delete provisioning profile. So it will remove it from your all existing Xcode application and even from your PC.
   [image: Photo is showing how to delete profile]