# How to remove provisioning profiles from Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile, ios-provisioning

Does anyone know how to remove previously installed provisioning profiles from Xcode?

I have seen [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/922695/removing-provisioning-profile-from-xcode), but I am not able to find that location in my system.

So I think there must be some other way to remove provisioning profiles.

Comment: Great question, applicable across all versions of Xcode. And there are some good answers here for previous versions, but for Xcode 9.1 none of answers seem to apply and/or work. Can someone provide an answer for the current version of Xcode? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 616, accepted):

It's simple, go to this folder:

```
~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning\ Profiles/
```

Open finder on your mac, and click on *Go -> Go to Folder ...* Just paste this into the search bar and hit *Open*. It will show the list of provisioning profiles present in Xcode. Delete all provisioning profiles.

Comment: `pkill -9 Xcode && rm ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning\ Profiles/* && open -a Xcode`

Answer (score 97):

#### Update for Xcode 8.3

This no longer works in Xcode 8.3. It appears to be related to Apple's move to automate provisioning profile and certificate generation:

[image]

The simplest "solution" (or workaround) is to make sure Xcode is closed, then via Terminal:

```
rm ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning\ Profiles/*.mobileprovision
```

---

#### In Xcode 7 & 8:

1. Open **Preferences** > **Accounts**
2. Select your apple ID from the list
3. On the right-hand side, select the team your provisioning profile belongs to
4. Click **View Details**
5. Under Provisioning Profiles, right-click the one you want to delete and select **Move to Trash:**

   [image]

Comment: I don't even have the "View Details" button. When I select my team, I'm seeing a "Download All Profiles" and "Manager Certificates..." button. Any idea?

Comment: @PhilippSumi With XCode 8.3 it is less simple to manually manage Provisioning profiles. The best thing to do is go to Finder>Go To Folder... and type in` ~/Library`. Once in the Library, navigate to /Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles. Here you can remove or add any profiles you want. If you want complete control, download individual profiles from your Apple Developer Portal and add those.

Comment: in 8.3.3 I removed the .mobileprovision files from the directory and they keep getting recreated in xcode when I click on "Download All Profiles" even though I've deleted all of the provisioning profiles on the apple web site

Comment: Also around version 8.3.3, the "View Details" option was removed and replaced with "Manage Certificates..."

Comment: Right, but that's just certificates now - it's no longer provisioning profiles.

Answer (score 81):

In Xcode 6, you can do this mostly right in Xcode:

1. Go to Xcode -> Preferences -> Accounts.
2. Choose your Apple ID in the left column.
3. In the right pane, click the "View Details..." button.
4. Right-click on the provisioning profile you want to delete, then click "Show Details".
5. A Finder window will open up with the provisioning profile highlighted.
6. Delete the selected provisioning profile.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. After deleting the provisioning profile in finder it shows up again when I hit refresh

Comment: Same as Kay, even if I also delete them off the website.

Comment: You need to right click on a profile and "view in finder". You can delete the actual file ... which is what worked for me! :D

Comment: This is ridiculous that one has to to this manually every time a renewal of provisional profiles is involved.  Apple, what has happened to you?

Comment: great. Thank you very much!

Comment: Note the the right-click menu is not available in Xcode 7.1. Instead, try the Finder-based solution by RIYAZ below.

Comment: @bruce1337, I just right-clicked on a provisioning profile in Xcode 7.1.1 and it showed a popup menu with the options "show in finder" and "move to trash".

Comment: @DuncanC you're right! For some reason Xcode doesn't recognize ctrl-click as equivalent to a right-click, even though Safari and other apps do.

Comment: @bruce1337, oh man, that's awful! Standard Apple equipment (Like Macbooks, or any trackpad device) often doesn't have a right mouse button. We should all file a radar bug about that.

Comment: Double finger tap on a selected item will get you the menu to "delete" or "show in finder" on a device with a trackpadI keep forgetting this. I always try a tap with a button combination which does not work.

Answer (score 25):

1. Open Terminal
2. cd ~/Library/MobileDevice/
3. open ./

Now the finder window will be open with Provisioning Profiles folder.
Delete all or any provisioning profiles from here and it will reflect in Xcode.

Comment: If you're using the terminal already, why not just use `rm` to remove profiles? Seems like a roundabout way to open finder

Comment: You are right. This is just a visually satisfying way to delete any specific group of provisioning profile from Finder.

Comment: If you want to do it ALL visually, no need Terminal.app. Just go to the Finder and press `Cmd` +`Shift` + `g` and paste: `~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles/` . Now you are in the right folder to remove your provisioning profiles at your own will :)

Answer (score 15):

. **Simple Steps:**

1:Click finder

2:Right click on Finder
3:click on **goto folder**

4: Paste in Search :
~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles

5:Click on **Go**

6:List of the Profiles .you can delete any one

**Thanks**

**You'll want to restart XCode to refresh the list.**

Answer (score 9):

I have found all my Distribution Profiles here:

**username -> libraries -> MobileDevice -> Provisioning Profiles**

[image]

Here I can check all profiles and kill expired.

Answer (score 8):

For Xcode 7, [brandonscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26732251/how-to-remove-provisioning-profiles-from-xcode-6-and-xcode-7/28513533#33027464) has the correct answer.

**For earlier versions:**

1. Log in to the Apple Developer member centre and delete the profile there: https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/profile/profileList.action
2. In Xcode you go to Preferences > Accounts and click on your apple ID and `View Details...`
3. Then Sync your online provisioning profiles to your local machine and the deleted ones will be removed from the list:

[image: synchronise provisioning profiles]

Comment: This doesn't work.  When I hit refresh they come back.  I've even tried wishab's suggestion - deleting them on disk AND online.  They won't die.  Provisioning profiles are the bane of my existence.

Comment: @David sorry to hear that. Maybe I'm the only lucky developer in the universe then: it works for me.

Comment: @David I totally agree with you & am having the same problem. They just won't die. Did you figure out the source of the problem yet? It's like a fungal infection.

Answer (score 7):

**In Xcode 7:**

1. Go to **Preferences** > **Accounts** > Select your account and click **View Details...**
2. In the Provisioning Profiles section, right click on the profile you want to delete and choose **Move to Trash**.
3. Click **Download all** to get all the latest profiles for your account, or click **Download** next to the profile.
4. Do a sanity check in your project's target(s) Build Settings so each target is indeed using the profile you want.

Answer (score 7):

open your terminal then use this command

```
cd /Users/youruser/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning\ Profiles/
```

check first inside your folder by use this command

```
ls
```

then if all files not use, delete by use this command

```
rm *
```

Answer (score 3):

-Download iPhone configuration utility tool

-open it-> In Library section:- select provisioning profile(Left side of tool)

-select provisioning profile(which you want to delete) using back space delete it.

Comment: Easiest option i find in this page.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to delete my Provisioning Profile from XCode 6 by using the Member Center online. I then just did a refresh/Sync in XCode 6 and it disappeared.

In the Apple Developer Member Center I had to do two things to make it happen:

- Under under `Identifiers -> AP IDs` I had to first delete the old AP ID still using the old Provisioning Profile that I wanted to delete.

  - This step was crucial for me. If I just deleted the Provisioning Profile alone without the APP ID still using it, the Profile re-appeared in XCode after a Sync.
- Under `Provisioning Profiles` I then deleted the unwanted provisioning profile.

In XCode:

- Under Preferences > Accounts, clicking on my apple ID and `View Details...` I Sync'd my online provisioning profiles.
- The Provisioning Profile removed itself from the list.

Comment: I also am having issues with my provisioning profile and APNs, using Xcode 6.3.2. But how can you delete an app ID? I aways thought and read it was not possible.

Answer (score 2):

For **XCode 9.3**, the following steps worked for me.

1. Go to Applications > Utilities > Keychain Access
2. Under the **login** option on the left panel, find **Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certification Authority**. Double click to get the options under it.
3. Under the Trust option, change the **When using this certificate** option to *Always trust* .
4. Exit the keychain access window, quit Xcode and restart Xcode. Rebuild the application. It should work now.

Comment: For me this did not work, but after I did this and cleaned the project, I was able to run without any errors of Provisioning Profile xD. 
So if this alone doesn't work, make sure you clean the project afterwards. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for sharing that! Yes, there is little clarity on what actually works given the frequent updates to Xcode too.

Comment: This broke Pods for me. I was able to compile but when loading I received dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/{framework} Reason: image not found. Revered back to system defaults and it worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

Post deleting and adding your new profile, you can verify if the profile is active and been take by your project by running below command.

```
grep -i "yourproject" *.mobileprovision
```

Comment: try to highlight the keywords and be clear with the format it will help to reach out your answer for others  Please [Take the Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 1):

Provisioning profiles are stored under settings > accounts. Just press the "View details..." for the developer account you want and the provisioning profiles will be listed there.

Comment: can you add a screen shot

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I do it.

```
Open Finder
Enable it to show hidden files (CMD_SHIFT_.)
Go to ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning\ Profiles
Delete the profile you wish ...
```

Answer (score -1):

I found out how to find provisioning profiles in Xcode 8. Archive your project (Product -> Archive) and then hit the validate button. Xcode will prepare the binary and the entitlements. When the summary windows comes up just hit the little arrow at the right of the window. A finder window will open with all your downloaded profiles.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QKP1N.png)

Answer (score -1):

With Xcode 9.3, this seems to be resolved by cleaning the project, quitting and restarting Xcode, and, after the restart, cleaning the build folder (hold Option and select Product->Clean Build Folder).

During the restart I happened to have the Xcode signing-info panel open on the Project navigator and saw a transient message that Xcode was rebuilding the signing profile.  Upon trying to run my project on a device, I got a runtime exception due to a Swift framework file having an invalid signature.  The second "Clean Build Folder" cleared that up and all works fine now.

Answer (score -2):

In xcode 6, provisioning profiles are stored under Xcode > Preferences > accounts. Press "View details". On selecting your profile, you will get option to revoke it under settings(gear) icon below.

Comment: I don't see a gear for provisioning profiles, only for signing identities.