# how to delete provisioning profile from xcode 7.2 in build settings

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I am working on may verison app. So for my first version i create a provisioning profile with some UDID . its name is `"testgrap"`. Now i moved to next version . So i again create a provisioning profile with another different `UDID`.Its name is"testgrap(2)".

Now under my build setting not able to see my provisioning profile `"testgrap(2)"`. Still my old version provisioning profile "testgrap" is there.

How can i get my new provisioning profile there.?

Comment: have u tried like this http://stackoverflow.com/a/33027464/5362916

Comment: Download nad install http://iphone-configuration-utility.soft32.com/mac/

Answer (score 3):

select xcode in the top menubar go to Window -> devices ->MyMac [image]

check the screen click on show Provisioning Profile, You will get all installed provisioning profiles in mac.

Answer (score 1):

To delete the provisioning profile go to xcode preferences and select accounts tab and there select your apple developer account and click on view details.

[image]

Then you will get a list of certificates and provisioning profiles. Select and right click on the provisioning profile on which you want to delete, then select move to trash. To get the newly added profile click on download all button then you will get all profiles in your account (it includes deleted one also. If you don't want that first click on download all and then later delete the old one).

[image]

There is another way to get new provisioning profile. Download the provisioning profile from apple developer center and double click on it, then it will automatically added in to xcode.

Answer (score 0):

1. Install iPhone Configuration Utility.
2. In the main window of this app select Provisioning Profiles.
3. Select the old provisioning profile (testgrap) from the list and delete it.
4. Make sure that the new profile is present and it matches your app's bundle id.
5. Quit and relaunch Xcode.

This should solve you issue.