# How to remove IOS team provisioning profile from account?

Tags: ios, xcode

I deployed some apps on Iphone and now i see all not used provisioning profiles. How i can remove this not used provisioning profiles from account? I have free developer account and i not have access to Certificates, IDs & Profiles in web site.[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove unused/expired provisioning profile from your apple developer account.

**You can follow these steps.**

step.1 Login to developer.apple.com with your Apple developer account

step.2 select **Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles**

[image]

step.3 scroll all the way to **Provisioning Profiles** option --> All

[image]

Now see while Provisioning profile you want to remove, select the one and --> Edit

[image]

Now you can delete!!

then you need to go to --> Xcode Preference --> Accounts and login with the same apple account, and refresh your certificates.

That's it!! it should help you.

**Note**: You must have edit/remove permission, if the certificates/profile were created by someone's developer account.

or

if you just want to remove provisioning profile from Xcode only, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26732251/how-to-remove-provisioning-profiles-from-xcode-6-and-xcode-7) one

Comment: sorry, but if i have free developer account i not have access to Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles. This whole problem(

Comment: @user3910670 of course that is the basic requirement, **you need to enroll in the Apple Developer Program**

Answer (score 0):

You have to delete all derived data from your Xcode and also delete unused provisional profiles from your apple account.