# CMake and Code Signing in XCode 8 for iOS projects

Tags: ios, xcode, cmake

CMake was able to configure automatic code signing for XCode <=7 and iOS projects with a target property setting like

```
set_target_properties(app PROPERTIES XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY "PROPER IDENTIFIER")
```

XCode 8 changed the signing process. It now is required that the option 
"Automatically manage signing" in the project settings "General tab -> Signing" is checked. If I check this options manually for a cmake generated project, signing works well. But I did not find a way to enable this option from cmake project by default. Can this be done for cmake (>=3.7.0)?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you want **automatic** signing in CMakeLists.txt

```
SET_XCODE_PROPERTY(MyTarget CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY "iPhone Developer")
SET_XCODE_PROPERTY(MyTarget DEVELOPMENT_TEAM ${DEVELOPMENT_TEAM_ID})
```

`DEVELOPMENT_TEAM_ID` - is your TeamID Eg. `2347GVV3KC`

---

If you want manual signing:

```
SET_XCODE_PROPERTY(MyTarget CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY ${CODESIGNIDENTITY})
SET_XCODE_PROPERTY(MyTarget DEVELOPMENT_TEAM ${DEVELOPMENT_TEAM_ID})
SET_XCODE_PROPERTY(MyTarget PROVISIONING_PROFILE_SPECIFIER ${PROVISIONING_PROFILE_NAME})
```

`CODESIGNIDENTITY` - Set to your preferred code sign identity, to see list: `/usr/bin/env xcrun security find-identity -v -p codesigning`

eg. `AAAAAAC9F10573BBBBBBBBBBBF25F7445951F3D8`

Or you can just write: `"iPhone Distribution"` but I'm not sure is it general rule :)

`PROVISIONING_PROFILE_NAME` - file name without extension eg. My full name: `Game_AppStore.mobileprovision` so here I write `Game_AppStore`

Provisioning profile previosly should be added to Xcode cache so it will be available in `~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning\ Profiles`
[More info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26732251/how-to-remove-provisioning-profiles-from-xcode)
You can simply do it from Xcode by clicking `Provisioning Profile: Name` and pick `Import Profile...` then select it. Remember when you invalidate it you need to remove it from cache.

---

`SET_XCODE_PROPERTY` is a macro:

```
# This little macro lets you set any XCode specific property
macro (set_xcode_property TARGET XCODE_PROPERTY XCODE_VALUE)
    set_property (TARGET ${TARGET} PROPERTY XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_${XCODE_PROPERTY} ${XCODE_VALUE})
endmacro (set_xcode_property)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can disable "Automatically manage signing" option by setting `XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_CODE_SIGN_STYLE` to **Manual**:

```
set_property (TARGET MyTarget PROPERTY XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_DEVELOPMENT_TEAM ${DEVELOPMENT_TEAM_ID})
set_property (TARGET MyTarget PROPERTY XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY ${CODESIGNIDENTITY})
set_property (TARGET MyTarget PROPERTY XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_CODE_SIGN_STYLE Manual)
```