# Using cmake to sign target

Tags: cmake, codesign, signtool, cpack

I was wondering if there's any specific command that performs codesign for application bundle or even a single executable file in macOS. The only way I've found out so far is
using the generic `add_custom_command` but perhaps there's an ad-hoc directive in cmake for this purpose which is also cross-platform (which means that in windows it will call signtool and in macOS/iPhone it will call codesign)

```
add_custom_command(TARGET myTarget POST_BUILD COMMAND ${CODESIGN_COMMANDLINE})
```

Comment: Note: I'm neither familiar with macOs bundles nor with codesign, but usually anything that builds some kind of package is handled by `cpack`; You may be able to achieve the desired result using the bundle using the [CPack Bundle Generator](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/cpack_gen/bundle.html). The linked site mentions a `CPACK_BUNDLE_APPLE_CODESIGN_FILES` variable which may indicate that this generator could work for you, but with my lack of experience in this regard I won't be able to tell myself (without spending more effort on a stackoverflow question than I'm willing to).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CMake and Code Signing in XCode 8 for iOS projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40664125/cmake-and-code-signing-in-xcode-8-for-ios-projects)

Answer (score 1):

CMake (CPack) does not have any unified or cross-platform support for signing anything.

However, since CMake 3.19 there is the [`CPACK_POST_BUILD_SCRIPTS`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/CPack.html#variable:CPACK_POST_BUILD_SCRIPTS) variable that can be used to perform any actions right after CPack finished building a package. For example, one can provide a CMake script to sign the package using whatever tool. It just makes unnecessary any special custom targets for package signing.