# Xamarin.iOS & XCode 8.3: how to download provisioning profiles?

Tags: ios, xcode, xamarin, xamarin.ios

Below is the the Xcode 8.3 interface for managing developer accounts, provisioning profiles, etc.

[image]

In earlier versions of Xcode it looked like this:

[image]

I cant seem to figure out how to use Xcode to download new or updated provisioning profiles in a manner that Xamarin Studio (Mac) will pick up on.

I did quite a bit of searching but cant seem to figure out how to do this in Xcode 8.3. I also tried a few command line approaches but to no avail.

Does anyone know how to do this using either Xcode 8.3 or manual approach?

Answer (score 6):

In xCode 8.3 the managing of provisioning profiles was moved from the Preferences-Accounts window to the specific project settings under Project-General tab.

From the "Xcode Release Notes" official documentation you'll find:

Provisioning - New Features:

> Changed the user interface for managing signing certificates and
>   provisioning profiles. Certificates are managed from the Accounts
>   preferences pane by selecting a team and clicking Manage Certificates.
>   Automatically managing signing is recommended, however if your app
>   requires manually signing provisioning profiles are managed in the
>   General tab of the project editor. Use the Provisioning Profile
>   dropdown to import or download profiles. In addition it displays
>   profiles that match the current signing configuration of the target.
>   For more information, see Xcode Help. (28641027)

Answer (score 0):

You should check the answer from [How to remove provisioning profiles from Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26732251/how-to-remove-provisioning-profiles-from-xcode-6-and-xcode-7). I checked off automatically manage signing and did it manually and it seems to work.

Hopefully this can help you as well,
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

The manual approach I have used is to delete the Xcode generated "Provisioning Profiles" folder.  This worked for me *today* using Xcode Version 8.3.3 (8E3004b)

- Close Xcode etc
- Delete Provisioning Profiles folder
- Restart Xcode and the folder will be recreated with the most recent copy of the profiles downloaded from Apple.

The folder is under your home directory:

```
~/Library/MobileDevice/
```

or

[image]