# Unable to use Beta with new devices id's for XCode 8.3.2

Tags: twitter-fabric, google-fabric, fabric-beta

Fabric mac app 2.6.11 will not get new provisioning profiles from xcode 8.3.2. After adding new device ids to developer.apple.com, going to Xcode File -> Preferences -> Accounts and clicking on Download All (no other option is offered) and going into Fabric, Archive, Distribute - the devices are still showing as not being added to the provisioning profile.

There is no longer the option of deleting profiles in XCode. There is only Download All.

Answer (score 4):

Mike from Fabric here. Based on [similar questions in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33027464/3975963), it appears that the way to do this is to close Xcode, then run the following command:

rm ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning\ Profiles/*.mobileprovision

Comment: That fixed it. Thank you!!

Comment: This worked for me too. Is there any chance there could be a patch made to Fabric so this manual step isn't required each time?

Comment: @MarkWatkins it should only be needed once; are you seeing this needed multiple times?

Comment: I did see  it more than once but I had some intervening build issues. Let me watch it when I add my next beta users and see if it happens again. It's a simple workaround - just very confusing to newbie users like myself, until you find this post :) - and thanks!!!

Comment: I seem to have to do this each time. I'm a n00b at xcode so it's entirely possible I am doing something wrong. I am using the new automatic signing option...still, deleting the file and rebuilding seems to make fabric happy and beta users can get the app...

Comment: Thanks for the details, I'll look into this further on our end, but this may also be a bug in Xcode.