# Invalid Provisioning Profile when building for release

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-sidekick

I am trying to build a release version of the app, I have downloaded and installed the distribution certificate and the right provisioning file but whenever I try to build locally it succeeds but when I try to upload it using Transporter I get the following error:
ERROR ITMS-90161: "Invalid Provisioning Profile. The provisioning profile included in the bundle com.cozycare.app [Payload/cozy.app] is invalid. [Missing code-signing certificate]. A Distribution Provisioning profile should be used when submitting apps to the App Store. For more information, visit the iOS Developer Portal."
The strange part is that if I build using cloud it works properly. Is there anything I should change in my xcode configuration? Or do you suggest anything else? I have spent the last 2 days trying to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

I followed this [answer](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/703995?answerId=710245022#710245022) which 100% works.

> Just get Xcode to redownload them by clearing out
> ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles. See
> https://twitter.com/hunter/status/1513960632059510784

1- close Xcode

2- to [clear](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31515645/4833705) it out, in terminal:

```
$ rm -rf ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning\ Profiles/
```

3- open `Xcode`, go to  `Preferences` > `Accounts` > **Select your team** > then select `Download Manual Profiles`

Answer (score -2):

I managed to solve the issue by changing the configuration for Signing & Capabilities and Build Settings in Xcode.

Comment: Elaborate more on your answer