# XCode iOS development and distribuiton certificate

Tags: ios, xcode

My certificates where expiring so I've created new ones via xcode,

Now when I try to update the expired ones the app xcode just get's stuck.

[image: After pressing download all]

I can press download all or update and it get's grayed out and stays like that.
I've tried deleting the account and adding it again with no luck.

Anyone else manage to solve this issue?

Comment: Not really what you would call elegant or correct solution. More like a tape-fix. I deleted the Provisioning profiles and certificates after removing the account. Then Added the account again. That fetched latest Certificates and Profiles.

Comment: I've removed the account also, but I don't know how to remove the provisioning profiles and certificates?

Comment: You can remove the certificates from Keychain Access and Profiles from ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles . It is by default a hidden folder.

Comment: Thank you it did the trick I found a more detailed explanation here http://stackoverflow.com/a/29576280/261363